# How to separate stringin databricks

Tags: databricks

I try to separete a string like `LESOES DO OMBRO (M75)` using a function split_part in databricks, but occurs an error: *AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'SPLIT_part'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'*. I need to separate the code in parentheses of the rest of the text.

I have a column "patologia" the column is for example `LESOES DO OMBRO (M75)` and I need a new column with the value M75

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and you need a new column with the value that's between parentheses in another column, then you can extract such value with regular expression, like this

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract

regex_df = spark.createDataFrame([("LESOES DO OMBRO (M75)",)], "patologia: string")
extracted_col_df = regex_df.withColumn("extracted_value", regexp_extract("patologia", r'\(([^)]+)\)', 1))
extracted_col_df.show()

+---------------------+---------------+
|patologia            |extracted_value|
+---------------------+---------------+
|LESOES DO OMBRO (M75)|M75            |
+---------------------+---------------+
```